# sql raiseerror error.number wrong in VB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, raiserror

I wrote a T-SQL query which includes a test for valid EmployeeNo. If the EmployeeNo is not valid, I do the following:

```
RAISERROR(5005, 10, 1, N'Invalid Employee No')
return @@Error
```

Back in VB.Net I test the sql exception and found that when the Employee No is invalid the error.number is not 5005 as I would expect, but 2732.

What is the explanation for this?

Thank you.

Comment: If you accepted more answers given to your questions you would be more likely to get many good quality answers on future questions. You can go back to your older questions and click the tick next to the most helpful answers.

Comment: 5005 is SQL Server error code and you are getting .Net framework error # in your code. If you want to preserve the original error# - pass it in the error text and then parse it out in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't raise an error 5005 in your own code. Only the DB Engine can do this.

Error 2732 is the error that says you can't raise [messages < 50000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177497.aspx)

```
SELECT description FROM sys.sysmessages m WHERE m.error = 2732 AND msglangid = 1033

Error number %ld is invalid. The number must be from %ld through %ld and it cannot be 50000.
```

Comment: > 50000 if you use sp_addmessage first. If you do RAISERROR ('A string'...) then it's always 50000